# Convert keycode to key char

Tags: .net

How do I convert a keycode to a keychar in .NET?

Answer (score 11):

In VB.NET:

```
ChrW(70)
```

In C# you can cast:

```
(char) 70
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this using a library class from user32.dll.
I would prefer a Framework class, but couldn't find one so this worked for me.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class KeyCodeToAscii

    <DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function ToAscii(ByVal uVirtKey As Integer, _
                                   ByVal uScanCode As Integer, _
                                   ByVal lpbKeyState As Byte(), _
                                   ByVal lpChar As Byte(), _
                                   ByVal uFlags As Integer) _
                                   As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function GetKeyboardState(ByVal pbKeyState As Byte()) _
      As Integer

    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetAsciiCharacter(ByVal uVirtKey As Integer) _
      As Char

        Dim lpKeyState As Byte() = New Byte(255) {}
        GetKeyboardState(lpKeyState)
        Dim lpChar As Byte() = New Byte(1) {}
        If ToAscii(uVirtKey, 0, lpKeyState, lpChar, 0) = 1 Then
            Return Convert.ToChar((lpChar(0)))
        Else
            Return New Char()
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: ToAscii is the key function, +1. However, see the remarks in MSDN: *The parameters supplied to the ToAscii function might not be sufficient to translate the virtual-key code, because a previous dead key is stored in the keyboard layout.*  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646316(v=vs.85).aspx --- Also, consider using ToUnicode instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found this snippet to be rather helpful in detecting a keypress from the enter key:

```
Private Sub StartValue_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles StartValue.KeyPress
    If ChrW(13).ToString = e.KeyChar And StartValue.Text = "" Then
        StartValue.Text = "0"
    End If
End Sub
```

I found this to be a decent solution to having people trying to submit a null value in a textbox. This just forces a 0, but it uses the "detect enter being pressed" to run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Char.ConvertFromUtf32(e.KeyValue)
```

Comment: This method does not take the Shift status into account. For example, keycode/value 65 returns 'A', but the key that was pressed was 'a' without Shift.

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter);

Comment: keys.numpad9="i", I think he was looking to convert to a matching character.

Answer (score -1):

I can't seem to reply to DaveH, but if you do as he says, it works fine!

```
  Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
  Public sub harry()
    For i = 1 to 255
      If Chr(i) = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
          Label1.Text &= " [Enter] "
      ElseIf Chr(i) = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Delete) Then
          Label1.Text &= " [Delete] "
      End If
    Next i
  End Sub
```

Comment: And whats the usage of call to WinAPI in your codes?!

Answer (score -1):

Here an example from my side :)

```
#region Just for fun :D

private string _lastKeys = "";

private readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> _keyChecker = _
    new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            // Key code to press, msgbox header, msgbox text
            {"iddqd", new[] {"Cheater! :-)", "Godmode activated!"}},
            {"idkfa", new[] {"Cheater! :-)", "All Weapons unlocked!"}},
            {"aAa", new[] {"Testing", "Test!"}},
            {"aaa", new[] {"function", "close"}}
        };

private void KeyChecker(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    _lastKeys += e.KeyChar;

    foreach (var key in _keyChecker.Keys)
        if (_lastKeys.EndsWith(key))
            if (_keyChecker[key][0] != "function")
                MessageBox.Show(_keyChecker[key][1], _keyChecker[key][0]);
            else
                KeyCheckerFunction(_keyChecker[key][1]);

    while (_lastKeys.Length > 100)
        _lastKeys = _lastKeys.Substring(1);
}

private void KeyCheckerFunction(string func)
{
    switch (func)
    {
        case "close":
            Close();
            break;
    }
}

private void FormMain_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    KeyChecker(e);
}

#endregion Just for fun :D
```

Comment: There is no keycode to char conversion in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

In VBA or Vb6:

Accessing from a KeyPress on a Button or other element sending a KeyCode:

```
Private Sub Command1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Label1.Caption = """" & KeyCodeToUnicodeString(CLng(KeyCode)) & """"
End Sub
```

In a module copy this code:

```
Option Explicit
'VB6
Private Declare Function ToUnicode Lib "user32" (ByVal wVirtKey As Long, ByVal wScanCode As Long, lpKeyState As Byte, ByVal pwszBuff As String, ByVal cchBuff As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetKeyboardState Lib "user32" (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long

''VBA
'#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
'    'VBA7 And Win64
'    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyboardState Lib "user32" (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long
'    'must be tested, maybe Long has to be replaced by Integer for 64 bit:
'    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ToUnicode Lib "user32" (ByVal wVirtKey As Long, ByVal wScanCode As Long, lpKeyState As Byte, ByVal pwszBuff As String, ByVal cchBuff As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
'#Else
'    'VBA 32 bit
'    Private Declare Function GetKeyboardState Lib "user32" (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long
'    Private Declare Function ToUnicode Lib "user32" (ByVal wVirtKey As Long, ByVal wScanCode As Long, lpKeyState As Byte, ByVal pwszBuff As String, ByVal cchBuff As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
'#End If

'Returns the text of the KeyCode pressed depending of the Keyboard language
'Does not work on Win98 (returns "") but works well on winXP and onwards
Public Function KeyCodeToUnicodeString(KeyCode As Long) As String
    On Error GoTo KeyCodeToUnicodeString_End
    Dim ret As Long
    Dim keyBoardState(0 To 255) As Byte
    Dim buffer As String * 256
    ret = GetKeyboardState(keyBoardState(0))
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Special: This portion of code is important for the function to work properly after compilation.
    'Why I do not know, but if removed, the next call to ret = ToUnicode will make a OutOfMemory Error
    'because the keyBoardState array is not yet in a correct state.
    'Tried Sleep or Byte b = keyBoardState(i) within the loop,
    'but the only way to make it work properlyIN vb6 is coded here.
    'If used in VBA, this part of code may be removed
    Dim s As String
    For i = 0 To 255
        s = s & CStr(keyBoardState(i)) & "-"
    Next i
    'end of special portion of code
    
    If ret <> 0 Then
        ret = ToUnicode(KeyCode, 0, keyBoardState(0), buffer, Len(buffer), 0)
        buffer = StrConv(buffer, vbFromUnicode)
        If ret <> 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            KeyCodeToUnicodeString = Left(buffer, InStr(buffer, vbNullChar) - 1)
        Else
            KeyCodeToUnicodeString = ""
        End If
    End If
KeyCodeToUnicodeString_End:
End Function
```

Comment: VBA and VB6 aren't .NET

Answer (score -3):

String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)

Comment: This is Javascript, not .NET, for anyone looking at this.